# How can I handle form submission without redirection visible to the user

Tags: jquery, python, django, forms

On my jobs page `http://127.0.0.1:8000/jobs/` I have two forms in the works. One for creating jobs, one for editing.  The one to add new jobs works just fine but I'm having issues managing the 2nd form for editing.

My view for adding jobs is:

```
def jobs(request):
    form = LimitedJobForm(request.POST or None, prefix='add')
    if form.is_valid():
      instance = form.save(commit=False)
      instance.save()

    context ={
    "form":form,
    }
    return render(request,"jobs.html",context)
```

My view for editing jobs is:

```
def editjob(request):
  # if request.is_ajax():
  jobnum = request.GET.get('jobnum')
  job_list = Job.objects.filter(jobnum=jobnum)
  json_data = serializers.serialize('json', job_list)
  a = json.loads(json_data)
  a = a[0]['pk'] #that's our pk!
# return JsonResponse(a,safe=False)

  j = Job.objects.get(pk=a) 
  editJobForm = JobForm(request.POST or None, prefix='edit',instance=j)
  if editJobForm.is_valid():
        frm_jobnum = editJobForm.cleaned_data.get("jobnum")
        frm_pm = editJobForm.cleaned_data.get("pm")
    #other fields redacted
        instance = editJobForm.save()
        instance.save()
  context ={
      "editJobForm":editJobForm,
    }
  return render(request, "editjob.html", context)
```

I have a button whose value updates based on selection of jobs in a table:

```
<button id='editjob' class='btn-primary'>Edit <span id='jobNum2'></span></button>
```

This jquery passes the button value to the edit view to get the pk for the job which then populates a form and adds it to a div on my `http://127.0.0.1:8000/jobs/` page.

```
//populate edit job form
$('#editjob').click(function(){
    var a = document.getElementById('jobNum').textContent
    $.ajax({
    url: "editjob",
    data: {'jobnum':a},
    success: function(data) {
        // console.log(data);
        $(".mydiv").html(data);
        document.getElementById('editform').action='editjob/?jobnum='+a;    
    },
    });
});
```

As you can see though, once the user submits the update for the job being edited they are redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/jobs/editjob/?jobnum=[some jobnum]` At this point, if there are no validation errors the update will have been saved to the database.  If there are validation errors, they will of course be shown on this page.  I want to be able to not have the user redirected to the /jobs/editjob page but I'm not sure how to best do this.  I had to modify the action of the edit job form to redirect otherwise django isn't able to understand which of the two forms on the page is being submitted as it was thinking the add job form was being submitted and triggering it's validation errors.

Comment: You can't use form submit if you don't want to refresh the page. You can only extract what's in the form and submit the data through ajax, so the form an its `action` is not that useful. Just out of curiosity, why do you put add job and edit job in the same page? It's might confuse the users.

Comment: Refreshing the page is fine. It's not doing that though, it's redirecting to a different page that also shows the same form that the user just submitted. Also, my page is designed well enough, I think, to avoid confusion. I work in the room across the hall were there any confusion

Comment: Don't forget to escape `a` with `encodeURIComponent(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `error` callback

> error
>
> Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String
>   errorThrown )
>
> A function to be called if the request fails. The
>   function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x,
>   XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that
>   occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible
>   values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error",
>   "abort", and "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown
>   receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found"
>   or "Internal Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can
>   accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn.
>   Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and
>   cross-domain JSONP requests. This is an Ajax Event.

So, you can reply with some `json` that contains information about the erros and to display this information within the `error` callback function

```
//populate edit job form
$('#editjob').click(function(){
    var a = document.getElementById('jobNum').textContent
    $.ajax({
    url: "editjob",
    data: {'jobnum':a},
    success: function(data) {
        // console.log(data);
        $(".mydiv").html(data);
        document.getElementById('editform').action='editjob/?jobnum='+a;    
    },
    error: function(jqXHR,textStatus, errorThrown){
         ........................................
         some actions that would be done on error
         ........................................
    }, 
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't see how this applies to my situation.